# Adding a ClientCertificate in Mono

Tags: ssl, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mono, client-certificates

I'm trying to make a HttpRequest in Xamarin (running Mono), but I think that ClientCertificates are not implemented in Mono. If I try to implement this, I get a NotImplementedException thrown.

```
var handler = new NativeMessageHandler();
handler.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate); //This line throws an exception

var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
```

I'm using the NativeMessageHandler from [this](https://github.com/alexrainman/ModernHttpClient) library.

Is there anyone that knows a workaround to this? The webapi I'm trying to communicate with requires me to use this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Using OkHttp on Android you would create a custom SSLSocket via SSLContext  and that gets passed to the OkHttpClient.Builder to use and then that SSLSocket can pass your custom client cert. On iOS via NSURLSession you can implement your own NSUrlSessionDelegate to define that DidReceiveChallenge returns your custom client cert.